# Redirect page upon login using react-router-v5

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux, react-router, react-router-dom

I am unable to get to get my application to render the component on sign in. When the user signs in, the url changes but the page does not load/redirect.

I have tried multiple solutions I found that utilize history.push/redirect and so on but nothing quite matches my use case or my implementation is no good.

I also tried solutions similar to [Redirect page upon login using react-router-v5 and redux-toolkit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154408/redirect-page-upon-login-using-react-router-v5-and-redux-toolkit) but had no luck.

All the other pages redirect as expected.

My repo is here: https://github.com/SerdarMustafa1/ad-app

app.js

```js
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <UsersContextProvider>
        <VehiclesContextProvider>
          <CampaignsContextProvider>
            <ClientsContextProvider>
              <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                  <ErrorBoundary>
                    <PersistGate persistor={persistor}>
                      <Suspense fallback={<Spinner />}>
                        <Route
                          exact
                          path="/login"
                          component={SignInAndSignUpPage}
                        />

                        <PrivateRoute path="/" exact component={Dashboard} />
                        {/* <PrivateRoute path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} /> */}
                        <PrivateRoute path="/userlist" component={UserList} />
                        <PrivateRoute
                          path="/campaignlist"
                          component={CampaignList}
                        />
                        <PrivateRoute path="/saleslist" component={SalesList} />
                        <PrivateRoute
                          path="/clientslist"
                          component={ClientsList}
                        />
```

The handle submit from my sign in form:

```js
  async handleSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    this.setState({ submitted: true });
    const { email, password } = this.state;
    const { dispatch } = this.props;
    if (email && password) {
      await dispatch(userActions.login(email, password));
    }
  }

.... removed for brevity....

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  const { loggingIn } = state.authentication;
  return {
    loggingIn,
  };
};

const connectedSignInPage = connect(mapStateToProps)(SignIn);
export { connectedSignInPage as SignIn };
```

user.services.js

```js
function login(email, password) {
  const requestOptions = {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify({ email, password }),
  };

  return fetch(`${config.apiUrl}/users/login`, requestOptions)
    .then(handleResponse)
    .then((user) => {
      // store user details and jwt token in local storage to keep user logged in between page refreshes
      localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
      console.log('------', user);
      return user;
    });
}
```

user.actions.js

```js
function login(email, password) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(request({ email }));

    userService.login(email, password).then(
      (user) => {
        dispatch(success(user));

        if (installerPermissions.includes(user.data.user.role)) {
          history.push('/installerApp');
        } else {
          history.push('/');
        }
        // console.log('test user dispatch', user);
      },
      (error) => {
        dispatch(failure(error));
        dispatch(alertActions.error(error));
      }
    );
  };

  function request(user) {
    return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_REQUEST, user };
  }
  function success(user) {
    return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_SUCCESS, user };
  }
  function failure(error) {
    return { type: userConstants.LOGIN_FAILURE, error };
  }
}
```

history.js

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export const history = createBrowserHistory();
```

auth-header.js

```js
export function authHeader() {
  // return authorization header with jwt token
  const user = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('user'));

  if (user && user.token) {
    return { Authorization: `Bearer ${user.token}` };
  }
  return {};
}
```

I am using:

```json
    "react-router": "^5.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "5.2.0",
```

Does anyone have anything else I can try or suggestions?

Any help would be much appreciated.

TIA

Comment: I am using both. You can see the switch in my first code block and I have import BrowserRouter as Router in my app.js.

Comment: In that case, you don't need to provide `history` to `BrowserRouter`. So, you can write : `<Router>` instead of `<Router history={history}>`. Note that if you want to provide `histroy` by yourself, you should use `Router` i.e. (`import {Router} from 'react-router-dom'`).

Comment: Tried those before but for arguments sake they did not work. removing the history={history} seem to not do anything. Whereas changing BrowserRouter to just router actually stopped any of the pages from loading.