# React-router: ProtectedRoute authentication logic not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, react-router, react-router-dom

I am trying to implement protected routes that are only accessible after the user logs in.

Basically, there are two routes: `/login` Login component (public) and `/` Dashboard component (protected). After the user clicks on the `Login` button in `/login`, an API is called which returns an `accessToken`, which is then stored in localStorage. The `protectedRoute` HOC checks if the token is present in the localStorage or not and redirects the user accordingly.

After clicking on the `Login` button it just redirects back to the login page instead of taking user to `Dashboard`. Not sure what is wrong with the logic.

`asyncLocalStorage` is just a helper method for promise based localStorage operations.

App.js

```
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./Dashboard";
import Login from "./Login";
import ProtectedRoute from "./ProtectedRoute";
import { asyncLocalStorage } from "./asyncLocalStorage";

function App() {
  const [auth, setAuth] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const getToken = async () => {
      const token = await asyncLocalStorage.getItem("accessToken");
      if (token) setAuth(true);
    };
    getToken();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="app">
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" isLoggedIn={auth} redirectTo="/login">
            <Dashboard />
          </ProtectedRoute>

          <Route exact path="/login">
            <Login />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

ProtectedRoute.js

```
import { Route, Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

const ProtectedRoute = ({ children, isLoggedIn, redirectTo, ...rest }) => {
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={() => {
        return isLoggedIn ? children : <Redirect to={redirectTo} />;
      }}
    />
  );
};

export default ProtectedRoute;
```

Dashboard.js

```
const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Dashboard</h3>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          localStorage.removeItem("accessToken");
          window.location.href = "/login";
        }}
      >
        Logout
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Dashboard;
```

Login.js

```
import { asyncLocalStorage } from "./asyncLocalStorage";

const Login = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          // Making an API call here and storing the accessToken in localStorage.
          await asyncLocalStorage.setItem(
            "accessToken",
            "SOME_TOKEN_FROM_API_RES"
          );
          window.location.href = "/";
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

asyncLocalStorage.js

```
export const asyncLocalStorage = {
  setItem: (key, value) => {
    Promise.resolve(localStorage.setItem(key, value));
  },
  getItem: (key) => {
    return Promise.resolve(localStorage.getItem(key));
  }
};
```

Comment: The order of asynchronous actions is often a problem.  I see that you are using `await` but you might still be hitting the redirect before `auth` has been set.  Does this help?: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66358676/10431574

Comment: Found it!  It's that you only run the effect to set `auth` once on mount, so `ProtectedRoute` **always** gets `isLoggedIn={false}`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem: `auth` State Never Updated

Your `ProtectedRoute` component relies on the value of `auth` from the `useState` in `App` in order to determine whether the user is logged in or not.  You set this value through a `useEffect` hook which runs once when the `App` is mounted.  This hook is never run again and `setAuth` is never called anywhere else.  If the user is logged out when `App` first mounts then the `ProtectedRoute` will **always** receive `isLoggedIn={false}` even after the user has logged in and the local storage has been set.

#### Solution: call `setAuth` from `Login`

A typical setup would check localStorage from the `ProtectedRoute`, but I don't think that will work with the `async` setup that you have here.

I propose that you pass both `isLoggedIn` and `setAuth` to the `Login` component.

```
<Login isLoggedIn={!!auth} setAuth={setAuth}/>
```

In the `Login` component, we redirect to home whenever we get a `true` value of `isLoggedIn`.  If a users tries to go to `"/login"` when they are already logged in, they'll get redirected back.  When the log in by clicking the button, they'll get redirected when the value of `auth` changes to `true`.  So we need to change that value.

The `onClick` handler for the `button` will `await` setting the token in storage and then call `setAuth(token)`.  This will trigger the redirection.

```
import { asyncLocalStorage } from "./asyncLocalStorage";
import {Redirect} from "react-router-dom";
const Login = ({isLoggedIn, setAuth}) => {
  if ( isLoggedIn ) {
    return <Redirect to="/"/>
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>Login</h3>
      <button
        onClick={async () => {
          // Making an API call here and storing the accessToken in localStorage.
          const token = "SOME_TOKEN_FROM_API_RES";
          await asyncLocalStorage.setItem(
            "accessToken",
            token
          );
          setAuth(token);
        }}
      >
        Login
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Login;
```

Comment: Checking "localStorage in ProtectedRoute.js" approach actually worked for me but, this approach seems better as there is one less localStorage operation. Thanks!!