# ComponentDidMount did not fire after using Redirect in react-router

Tags: reactjs

so i was using `redirect` in `react-router-dom`, i have 2 pages, `home` and `create` when the form in `create` is done and has been submitted, it will execute the `<Redirect>` function, and it works, but the `ComponentDidMount` was not being fired again, i need to reload the page to make the `ComponentDidMount` to make it start again, here is my code

this is how i `redirect` in the `Create` file :

```
if(this.state.createNew){
        return <Redirect to='/home'/>
    }
```

and this is my `ComponentDidMount` in my `Home` file :

```
componentDidMount() {
    console.log("hi")
    }
```

the console print `hi` only on the initial render, when i redirect back to the page it does not fire again, i tried use `setState` inside the `ComponentDidMount` but it still not being re rendered.

when i tried using `Link to` method, it works, the `ComponentDidMount` is being fired again, but `Link to` is not what i want, because it does not automatically redirect like the `<Redirect>` do

i got an error when i try to use the `useHistory` function :

```
React Hook "useHistory" is called in function "simpan" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks
```

here is how i use my `useHistory` :

```
function simpan(event){
    event.preventDefault()
    const email = event.target.elements.email.value
    const name = event.target.elements.name.value
    const admin = event.target.elements.admin.value
    const active = event.target.elements.active.value
    const history = useHistory()
    console.log(email)
    history.push('/home')
}
```

thanks before, anyhelp will be appriciated

Answer (score 1):

instead of `<Redirect />` why don't you use `history.push('/home')`. this will take you to the new route once state is true and call `componentDidMount`

how to use history:

`import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'`

then inside your component: `const history = useHistory()`

then whether you need to change the route:

`history.push('/home')`

Comment: history is not a function from `React-Router` am i correct ?

Comment: you can use `useHistory` hook if you are using `react-router` v5

Comment: if you're using v4 then check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4

Comment: @Walls have edited my answer to show you how to use `useHistory` in v5

Comment: i got an error when i try to use `useHistory`, i will update my question to show you my errors

Comment: sure. remember to include the error message too so I can help!

Comment: oh. it's coz you're using a class component. let me change my answer again for that. one sec

Comment: i have checked my version and a possible duplicate of react but i dont have any of it

Comment: are you able to change it to a functional component? instead of a class component

Comment: if you post your entire code for that class I can convert it for you

Comment: then you can use hooks

Comment: can we continue in chat ?

Comment: sure. how about posting your code in a sandbox or something?

Comment: hmm i dont think i can use a functional component for this one, sorry

Comment: you can always use a functional component :D they are better and more performant too. and will allow you to mondernise and use hooks which is "good practice" in React nowadays

Comment: ok i changed my code to a functional, here is my code, but i still got an error, i will update it

Comment: `simpan` isn't a functional component. it's just a function. you need to return something for it to be a functional component. why don't you call this function inside your functional component?

Answer (score 0):

If your `create` is class component just use `this.props.history.push("/home")` instead of `<Redirect>` tag.
As `create` component is your route it will automatically get `history` object in `props`.
[why to use history instead of redirect tag in your case](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-programmatically-navigate/)

[Simple example of programatic navigation with react routing](https://programatic-react-routing.stackblitz.io) Please check console of browser while checking this example

Comment: the page does not change when i use this method, i still need to reload the page