# useState with value that may be null

Tags: reactjs

I am new to React and have a question about `useState`. I have this code:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote.content);
```

The problem is that `selectedNote` is sometimes `null` and sometimes not. If it is `null` then this throws an error. **How can I work around this?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) is fantastic:

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content);
```

If you want a default value in the case that selectedNote (or content) is null/undefined then you can use [nullish coalescing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Nullish_Coalescing_Operator)

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content ?? 'default');
```

Comment: This works!! One question: for some reason `value` doesn't change when `props.selectedNote?.content` changes. Do you know why this could be?

Comment: The `(props.selectedNote?.content)` is the initial value of the state. After that, the state is set. So, you'd need a `useEffect(()=>{setValue(props.selectedNote?.content)},[props.selectedNote?.content])` to update the state every time the selectedNote changes. Otherwise you might not want to `useState` for it and just pull the content into a variable and use that.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

`const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?props.selectedNote.content:null)`

Answer (score 0):

You can manage it with a ternary operator as suggested by @deepakgupta. Another possibility, useful when you have a lot of props to check, is that of assign `defaultProps` to the component. This will avoid all a bunch of check inside component body and let the code more clean.

```
function myComponent(props) {
    const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote.content);
}

myComponent.defaultProps = {
    selectedNote : {
        content : null
    }
    ...
    anotherProp : 'my default value'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's depends from your application business logic.

1. Conditional Rendering

```
const Comp = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content);

   return value ? < some your staff > : <SkeletonForNoValue />;
}
```

2. You may define default value

```
const Comp = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content || defaultNote);
```

3. Push to another route

```
const Comp = (props) => {
   const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content);

   useEffect(
     () => {
        history.push({
          pathname: '/path/to/go'
        }
     },
     [props.selectedNote]
   )
```

- about history - [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

4. Any other logic implementation...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote && props.selectedNote.content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this : `const [value, setValue] = useState(props.selectedNote?.content || defaultNote);`