# Why is props.history.push() is not redirecting

Tags: reactjs, firebase-authentication, react-router

In my react app I am trying to redirect using `props.history.push()` on the click of a button but unfortunately, it isn't redirecting (yes, I checked if the path exists). This is the exact function that is getting triggered when the button is clicked.

If I put `props.history.push()` above `await firebaseApp.signUp(username, email, password)` then it works, but that doesn't make much sense, as I will be redirected even if I have errors.

```
const signup = async () => {
  try {
    await firebaseApp.signUp(username, email, password);
    props.history.push("/daily");
  } catch (error) {
    alert(error.message);
  }
};
```

This is the signUp function defined in firebaseApp class:

```
  async signUp(name, email, password){
    await this.auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    return this.auth.currentUser.updateProfile({
      displayName:name
    })
```

What is the solution to this problem?

Comment: are you sure this function is working firebaseApp.signUp? are you getting any errors?

Comment: nope not at all cause the account is getting created in my firebase authentication section

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a while back.

Here's how I fixed it -

**history.js**

```js
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';

export default createBrowserHistory();
```

App.js

```js
class App extends Component {
    render() {  
    return(
   <Router history={history}>
      <Router history={history}>
                <Switch>
                    <Route
                        path="/sign-up"
                        render={(props) => <SignUpForm {...props} />}
                    />

                    <PrivateRoute
                        exact
                        path={ROUTES.HOME}
                        component={Homepage}
                    />

                </Switch>
            </Router>
     );
   }
 }
```

SignUpForm.js

```js
import history from "./Routes/history";

class SignUpForm extends React.Component {

    handleSignUp = (e) => {
  //Add your success logic here
                    history.push("/home");
                }
    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.handleLogin}>
                <div className="form-submit">
                    <Button
                        variant="outline-success"
                        size="xs"
                        block
                        type="submit"
                    >
                      Submit
                    </Button>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
  );
}
 }
```

Comment: dont u think its just too much efforts for such a small thing cause the problem is that I have a lots of components in my app so I will have to pass history in props for every component in create..Is there any other way? @theabrar

Comment: @Pranil you can look at a previous discussion on this topic -

https://stackoverflow.com/a/42716055/14492980