# useHistory hook is not working although console doesn't show errors

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-router, react-hooks, react-functional-component

I am trying to navigate to another page after Firebase sign up finishes, so I tried to use useHistory hook to navigate to next page after signing up is successful
the signing up was successful but the hook doesn't work, the console doesn't show any errors

and if the hook doesn't work for such case, how can I navigate to next page if sign up was successful?

```
    import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
const history = useHistory();
      function signup(event) {
        console.log({email, password});
        
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((user) => {
            // Signed in 
            // ...
            
            this.history.push('/Quiz')
            console.log(email, password)
            
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({ email: user.email, password: user.password });
           
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
            console.log(errorMessage)
            
          });
          
      }
```

Comment: use `history.push('/Quiz')` instead of `this.history.push('/Quiz')`

Comment: It didn't work either

Comment: It gave error "react hooks can't be used inside callbacks"

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45849608/6516699), this might be helpful

Comment: try doing a `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: Already done as in the post

Comment: no in the post you are doing `console.log(errorMessage)` ,instead do `console.log(error.message)`

Comment: Already this will log out errors for the sign up and not the navigation and the sign up is successful I checked firebase

Answer (score 0):

you can to this

app.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";
import Routes from './routes'
const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(<Router history={history}><Routes/></Router>, node);
```

signup.js

```
      import {useHistory} from 'react-router-dom'
      const AppName = () => {
      const history = useHistory();

      function signup(event) {
        console.log({email, password});
        
        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
          .then((user) => {
            // Signed in 
            // ...
            
            history.push('/Quiz')
            console.log(email, password)
            
            firebase.database().ref('users/' + user.uid).set({ email: user.email, password: user.password });
           
          })
          .catch((error) => {
            var errorCode = error.code;
            var errorMessage = error.message;
            // ..
            console.log(errorMessage)
            
          });
          
      }
    return (...)
}
```

Comment: I imported it already but didn't include it in the post

Comment: And removing this didn't help

Comment: You have packed history in package.json, if you haven't installed package history, please do the installation npm install history

Comment: What's package history? I installed react-router-dom

Comment: because using useHistory, it needs history for it to work

Comment: Are you sure the package's name is "history"?

Comment: yes, you have to configure with history and react-router-dom and it works

Comment: import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history';  export const history = createBrowserHistory()

Comment: Where should that import/export happen?can you please edit the answer with it?

Comment: I tried your solution and it doesn't work either

Comment: I am getting "history is not imported from history.js"