# Uncaught TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useHistory) is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am working with a migration project, I do not have much idea about `react-router-dom 4.3.1`.

My React version is: `React.version '16.14.0'` and the router dom is `react-router-dom": "^4.3.1"`. When I use the `goBack()` from history getting an error as:

`TypeError: (0 , _reactRouterDom.useHistory) is not a function`

Code:

```
import { NavLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const goBackToPreviousPage = () => {
  const history = useHistory();
  history.goBack();
};

<button onClick={goBackToPreviousPage}>
  Back to previous page
</button>
```

Comment: Hooks were added in `react-router-dom` 6.x

Comment: @Konrad, how about 4.x?

Comment: In which type of components the code snippet you posted is placed, class or function based?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to push to History in React Router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42701129/how-to-push-to-history-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: @AlanOmar - it's functional based

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `useHistory` hooks was introduced in `react-router@5`, as well as [`useLocation`, `useParams`, and `useRouteMatch` hooks](https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks). `react-router@4` and `react-router@5` are generally considered to be the same "version". The v4 [docs](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/tree/v4.0.0) even link to the official v5 docs.

My suggestion if you want to avoid actual major breaking changes (*i.e. upgrading to v6 would be a lot of work*) and use the `useHistory` hook is to simply upgrade from v4 to v5.

1. Uninstall any existing `react-router` and `react-router-dom` versions.

   `npm uninstall --save react-router`

   `npm uninstall --save react-router-dom`
2. Install `react-router-dom` v5 latest. RRD re-exports all of `react-router` so there's no need to have both installed as dependencies.

   `npm install --save react-router-dom@5`

Note that the code still needs to follow the Rules of Hooks. The `useHistory` hook cannot be called in the callback, but must be called in the React Function component body.

```
import { NavLink, useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const Component = () => {
  const history = useHistory();

  ...

  const goBackToPreviousPage = () => {  
    history.goBack();
  };

  ...

  return (
    ...
    <button onClick={goBackToPreviousPage}>
      Back to previous page
    </button>
    ...
  );
}
```

Or more succinctly:

```
const history = useHistory();

...

<button onClick={history.goBack}>
  Back to previous page
</button>
```