# React router nivagate after login

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Trying to implement redirect after login success. 
`history.pushState(null,null, '/profile')` doesn't work. Just change URL and all. 
`browserHistory.push('/profile');` Same

How do i can create redirect after login?

```
        case types.LOG_IN_SUCCESS:
        history.pushState(null,null, '/profile');
```

Thanks

Comment: What does "doesn't work" mean? Be specific.

Comment: @Jordan, This changes the URL to /profile but does not render the components in that route. Means doesn't navigate to new page

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatic redirect after login with react-router](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594720/automatic-redirect-after-login-with-react-router)

Answer (score 0):

React Router has `replace` method instead of `transitionTo` for redirects.
If you have some old version of Router you may need to use `transitionTo`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594720/automatic-redirect-after-login-with-react-router) from Michelle Tilley.

---

I think in your case you may use (no need for `this` depends on the version you have):

```
var Router = require('react-router');
Router.browserHistory.push('/somepath');
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to call the push method on the router:

```
this.context.router.push('/profile');
```

In case you need router in your Login component - if you add this you will have router.

```
LoginComponent.contextTypes = {
    router: React.PropTypes.object.isRequired
};
```