# Header/Footer navigation react-router-dom and antd menu and router problems

Tags: reactjs, react-router, antd

I am working on a reactjs application - and I've created two menus - header/footer -- I've noticed a bug on the "active" state when I navigate on the pages.

// Current problems

1. When arriving on home page the home link is active on the header menu, but when clicking on the footer menu - privacy - the privacy link is active but the header links are also still active when they should be deactived.
2. Also when going to a page that doesn't exist like typing /home2 -- it should bounce to the Error page but it doesn't - what is interfering with this in the router?

// Land on home page -- home page is active
[image]

// Land on privacy - privacy is active in the footer - but the home page in the header is also still active.

[image]

// Header.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Menu, Icon, Alert } from 'antd'

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

// this is a class because it needs state
class Header extends Component {

  state = {
    current: 'home',
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
        mode="horizontal"
      >
        <Menu.Item key="home">
          <Link to="/home" rel="noopener noreferrer">Home</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="account">
          <Link to="/account" rel="noopener noreferrer">Account</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}

export default Header
```

// Footer.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom'
import { Row, Col, Menu, Icon, Alert } from 'antd'

const SubMenu = Menu.SubMenu;
const MenuItemGroup = Menu.ItemGroup;

// this is a class because it needs state
class Footer extends Component {

  state = {
    current: 'home',
  }

  handleClick = (e) => {
    console.log('click ', e);
    this.setState({
      current: e.key,
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {    

  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Menu
        onClick={this.handleClick}
        selectedKeys={[this.state.current]}
        mode="horizontal"
      >
        <Menu.Item key="about">
          <Link to="/about" rel="noopener noreferrer">About</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="terms">
          <Link to="/terms" rel="noopener noreferrer">Terms of Service</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
        <Menu.Item key="privacy">
          <Link to="/privacy" rel="noopener noreferrer">Privacy Policy</Link>
        </Menu.Item>
      </Menu>
    )
  }
}

export default Footer
```

// router.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Redirect, Switch } from 'react-router-dom'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, compose } from 'redux'

// components
import Login from './components/Login/Login'

import Home from './components/Home/Home'
import Account from './components/Account/Account'

import About from './components/About/About'
import Terms from './components/Terms/Terms'
import Privacy from './components/Privacy/Privacy'

import Error from './components/Error/Error'

import Header from './components/Header/Header'
import Footer from './components/Footer/Footer'

const history = createBrowserHistory()

//const store = createStore(rootReducer, compose(
const store = createStore(compose(
  typeof window === 'object' && typeof window.devToolsExtension !== 'undefined' ? window.devToolsExtension() : (f) => f
  )
)

// we can pass the lang files as props to the routes
// we should have a nested route inside service here to show the other services page

class Routes extends Component {
  render () {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Router history={history}>
          <div className='off-canvas-wrap' data-offcanvas>
            <div className='inner-wrap'>
              <Header transparent />
              <Switch>
                <Route path='/home' component={Home} />
                <Route path='/account' component={Account} />

                <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route path='/terms' component={Terms} />
                <Route path='/privacy' component={Privacy} />

                <Route path='/login' component={Login} />
                <Route path='/' component={Login} />
                <Route component={Error} />
              </Switch>
              <Footer transparent />
            </div>
          </div>
        </Router>
      </Provider>
    )
  }
}

export default Routes
```

Comment: What is your react router version?

Comment: "react-router-dom": "^4.2.2",

Comment: -- is it just because the header/footer components need to have some deselect if NOT on page?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [react router 4](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/philosophy)

you can use `NavLink`. It providing the [`activeClassName`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeClassName-string) and [`activeStyle`](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink/activeStyle-object) options for adding 
class and activeStyle

**activeClassName**

`<NavLink
  to="/about"
  activeClassName="selected">about
</NavLink>`

**activeStyle**

```
<NavLink
  to="/about"
  activeStyle={{
    color: 'red'
   }}
>about</NavLink>
```

> **Also when going to a page that doesn't exist like typing /home2 -- it should bounce to the Error page but it doesn't - what is interfering with this in the router?**

The issue is here :

```
<Route path='/' component={Login} />
```

In case no route is match,it will render to `Login` component and not a `Error` component

You must add `exact` to `Route` to get 404 behaviour of `Error` component.

Correct way to do this.

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
```

Comment: - but it's using antd menu -- I suppose for the footer I could use NavLink -- but for the header use menu -- I also want to configure the header menu to compact on responsive

Comment: -- I see -- yes I had it as / for the login page -- but you are saying I should do the exact path for the login page -- ok should I have it just /login - and use a redirect on / ? -- I only want them to bounce to the login page if they are NOT logged in -- otherwise I suppose the home page is where they would go

Comment: `should I have it just /login - and use a redirect on / ?` yes.Jst bounce to /ogin if no login

Comment: -- ok - could you do a demo of this - if logged in/not logged bounce --   import { Route, Redirect } from 'react-router'

<Route exact path="/" render={() => (
  loggedIn ? (
    <Redirect to="/dashboard"/>
  ) : (
    <PublicHomePage/>
  )
)}/>

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34735580/how-to-do-a-redirect-to-another-route-with-react-router

Comment: Also - should I remove the menu in the footer for the NavLink parts -- I think I still need a way to deselect the header menu antd -- so its not on the page it handles not to select any link?

Comment: -- I've also seen methods to do a pushstate? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29594720/automatic-redirect-after-login-with-react-router

Comment: -- documentation on the NavLink and Link -- https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: ok so how would I deselect the header menu if I've clicked on footer links or refreshed the page on footer links? I have tried to SET the state from the routing level -- checking on which page the user is on and feeding it into the header and footer components -- http://jsfiddle.net/0ht35rpb/105/

Comment: I need your assistance on a register form -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45942891/reactjs-redux-storing-data-from-a-form-submission

Comment: @TheOldCounty sure

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in your ***route component*** this line arises issue:-

```
 <Route path='/' component={Login} />
```

it must be like

```
<Route exact path='/' component={Login} />
```

if you won't use the `exact` attribute, every time it will match with the routing `/`. So you need to add an `exact` keyword to avoid this issue.