# How to redirect to some other route after successful authentication in react-admin

Tags: react-admin

I have been looking for a solution to redirect to specific url after successful authentication in react-admin,

when I paste `http://localhost:1234/#/students/sdf2343afs32` on the url if already signed-in then I'm getting the user detail page but if not singed-in and after singing-in it shows  home page instead

Answer (score 4):

You can customize the redirect URL after login inside the `authProvider` as explained in the [Checking Credentials During Navigation](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Authentication.html#checking-credentials-during-navigation) part of the documentation:

```
// in authProvider.js
import { AUTH_CHECK } from 'react-admin';

export default (type, params) => {
    // ../
    if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
        return isLogged
            ? Promise.resolve({ redirectTo: '/custom-url' })
            : Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/no-access' });
    }
    // ...
};
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, seems Promise.resolve({ redirectTo: '/custom-url' }) not working when i use the reject it redirects, or anything missing in my code?

Comment: I believe `Promise.resolve({ redirectTo: '/custom-url' })` should merely act as a guidance.

Comment: Sure, you have to build your own URL from the params.

Comment: This answer is wrong. redirectTo only works for logout, and not for login as the orig question stated

Answer (score 2):

Based on https://stackoverflow.com/a/35715159/986160 using react-admin 2.6.2

What worked for me is a custom Dashboard like that (assuming this is your default landing page):

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user_role") !== "special_role") {
            return <Card>
                <CardHeader title="Welcome to Dashboard" />
                <CardContent></CardContent>
            </Card>
        }
        else {
            return (<Redirect to="/route/to/redirect" />);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose the redirect-to url is unknown at build time. What he asks is for redirecting to any url that the user pasted on the address bar, right after login.

Comment: this will never work since pasting a url in browser will do a full reload of the application

Comment: What is wrong with a full reload? After full reload the app should read the url. If it is not authenticated, then redirect to login page, and after login should redirect to the url it read in the beginning.

Comment: @ThanasisIoannidis after url copy paste spa starts again and then router is engaged.. your dashboard resides on '/dashboard' and redirection route should be known in advance - so it can't be dynamic for this particular case - of course you could have custom routes anywhere on the react-router that would work as usual