# How to redirect to some other route after successful authentication in react-admin?

Tags: reactjs, promise, react-admin

Using react-admin.

I have the same question as this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060397/how-to-redirect-to-some-other-route-after-successful-authentication-in-react-adm), because the answer didn't work neither to me nor to the person who asked (see the comments). After the major release update, is there another option to redirect to a custom page after the successful login?

The code:

Inside my custom authProvider, when checking authentication, I am trying to redirect to a custom page:

```
if (type === AUTH_CHECK) {
     ...
      if (localStorage.getItem("pageID")) {
            return Promise.resolve() // goes to Dashboard
     else {
        return Promise.resolve({ redirectTo: '/pages' }); // needs to go to a custom page
    }
```

However, the `Promise.resolve({ redirectTo: '/pages' })` simply does not work.

If I use `Promise.reject({ redirectTo: '/pages' })` indeed, it tries to redirect to `pages`, however, as the `AUTH_CHECK` is failing, it returns to login and stay in loop.

I also tried put this code inside the AUTH_LOGIN, but it does not work as well.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to some other route after successful authentication in react-admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52060397/how-to-redirect-to-some-other-route-after-successful-authentication-in-react-adm)

Answer (score 1):

Currently `userLogin` action doesn't handle redirect path url that is the reason you are not getting redirected. 
There are two ways you can achieve this. Custom login page or Custom dashboard compoenent

**Custom login page**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { userLogin } from 'react-admin';

class MyLoginPage extends Component {
    submit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        // gather your data/credentials here
        const credentials = { };

        // Dispatch the userLogin action (injected by connect)
      if (localStorage.getItem("pageID")) {
        this.props.userLogin(credentials, "/pages");
      }else {
        this.props.userLogin(credentials);
      }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <form onSubmit={this.submit}>
            ...
            </form>
        );
    }
};

export default connect(undefined, { userLogin })(MyLoginPage);
```

**Custom DashBoard**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { push } from 'react-router-redux';


export class MyDashBoard extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
          if (localStorage.getItem("pageID")) {
            push("/pages");
          }
    }

    render() {
        return (

        );
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't make it work based on other answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/52360387/986160) so I did like that for react-admin 2.6.2:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54422728/986160

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Redirect } from 'react-router';
import Card from '@material-ui/core/Card';
import CardContent from '@material-ui/core/CardContent';
import CardHeader from '@material-ui/core/CardHeader';

export default class Dashboard extends Component {

    render() {
        if (localStorage.getItem("user_role") !== "special_role") {
            return <Card>
                <CardHeader title="Welcome to Dashboard" />
                <CardContent></CardContent>
            </Card>
        }
        else {
            return (<Redirect to="/route/to/redirect" />);
        }
    }
}
```